# Get the values of columns of Doctrine 2 entity - not objects, just values

Tags: doctrine-orm

Let's say I have an entity called `Game` which has a `home_school_id`. I can of course do `$myGame->getHomeSchool()->getId()` if I want that school's id, but that takes up too much memory. How can I just directly get `home_school_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your GameRepository.php. Then, do a $game->getHomeSchoolId($id);
You'll just have to work with your select, from and where, but that's really easy.

```
    public function getHomeSchoolId($id)
    {
        return $this
                ->_em
                ->createQueryBuilder()
                ->select('q.home_school_id')
                ->from('BundleMyBundle:HomeSchool', 'q')
                ->where('q.something = :id')
                ->setParameter('id', $id)
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult();
    }
```

If you want the ID of another entity, which is linked through a relation, you'll have to do a join. Just ask if you need more informations.